# Unity IVRRenderModels_006 SteamVR Error

Tags: unity, virtual-reality, steam-vr, error-management

I get this Error in Unity when I imported SteamVR :
"Failed to Load IVRRenderModels Interface Version IVRRenderModels_006"
I looked after on it but nothing really solved the problem.
Why is this happening and what could be the solution?

Comment: Can you tell us more about your setup? eg. Have you installed Steam VR on your system? What model of headset have you connected? [Have you tried applying this answer](http://answers.unity.com/answers/1362612/view.html)?

Comment: Telling the truth originally I would have a VR Set from the university, but because of the epidemic, my Uni is closed so I try making it without a VR Set

Comment: You will need an HMD to proceed. The errors you're reporting in this question and your other question are due to not having an HMD attached.

Comment: Yes, I had an idea this is the problem, so I changed the plan and I will make a Mobile VR app.
Thank you very much for your help anyway. I really appreciate it.